# Force .append() to actually append on each iteration, not just overwrite with last iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

My code loops through a js arrray\object in order to append some of the stored values in some text areas, however, it's only appending the last iteration. (or overwriting instead of appending on each iteration.)

I've tried all solutions mentioned here: https://dzone.com/articles/why-does-javascript-loop-only-use-last-value during my research, but no luck.

```
for (var j = 0; j < data['formValues'][0].length; j++) {
      //start appending on certain fields only
      if (data['formValues'][0][j]['name'] == 'DynamicTextBox') {
            var k = j;
            //l can't be larger than array length
            var l = k + 1;
            if (l === data['formValues'][0].length) {
                l = data['formValues'][0].length - 1;
                //compensate for loop increment
                k--;
                //render
                $("#TextBoxContainer").append(
                    '<div><textarea name="DynamicTextBox" rows="5">' + data['formValues'][0][k]['value'] + '</textarea>' + '<textarea name="DynamicTextBox" rows="5">' + data['formValues'][0][l]['value'] + '</textarea>' + '<button type="button" value="Remove" class="remove">Remove</button></div>'
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `append()` does not overwrite anything. If that's the behaviour you're seeing then there must be some other logic either interfering with either your array or the element you're appending to. Could you edit your question to include a working example of the problem.

Comment: All the examples in that dzone link use closures / deferred execution / async code (eg setTimeout).  There's no async code in what you've provided, so that's not the cause.

Comment: It's an easy check, just before your `.append` add `console.log(j,k,l, data['formValues'][0][k]['value'])` and see how many times it appears - if it appears multiple times with *different* values, then you have an overwrite scenario (which is impossible with `.append()` as already stated).  If it appears multiple times with the *same* values then you have the issue in the link.   If it only appears **once** (as will be the case here) then it's a simple logic issue (the `===` before the .append).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not `append()`, it's what you do with your `k` and `l` variables. Specifically, you only execute the append once, on the last loop, because you check `(l === data['formValues'][0].length)`, which is only true on the last iteration.

If you just want one textbox per iteration, remove all the k and l stuff and just do:

```
for (var j = 0; j < data['formValues'][0].length; j++) {
    //start appending on certain fields only
    if (data['formValues'][0][j]['name'] == 'DynamicTextBox') {
        $("#TestTextBoxContainer").append(data['formValues'][0][j]['value'] + ' ');

        //render
        $("#TextBoxContainer").append(
            '<div><textarea name="DynamicTextBox" rows="5">' + data['formValues'][0][j]['value'] + '</textarea>' + '<button type="button" value="Remove" class="remove">Remove</button></div>'
        );

    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Luvc982z/7/